# SkypeForBusiness deprecation on BotFramework

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

It has been some time I didn't go to my bot channels registration on azure but today I noticed a banner stating :

> Alert! Skype for Business channel is being deprecated on July 1, 2019.
>   Microsoft Teams is a recommended solution. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview).

But the link is about creating a bot on teams, so not much information about the deprecation.

Does anyone have more information about this and what does it mean for existing solutions based on Skype For Business channel ? (complete shutdown on the 1th of July ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the official documentation:

> Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated on June 30, 2019.
>
> No new bots will be able to add Skype for Business channel after that
>   date. Existing bots will continue to work until October 31, 2019.
>   Microsoft Teams is the preferred communication tool from Microsoft.

As it says, you won't be able to add Skype for Business as a channel after Jun 30, and bot that are currently on Skype for Business will not longer work on Nov 1.

[Skype for Business Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)